# what is wrong with this piece of code I have been asked

Tags: c

```
#include <string.h>

void foo (char *bar)
{

    char c[12];
    strcpy(c, bar);

}
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

    foo(argv[1]);
    return(1);

}
```

Comment: What's it supposed to do? This does nothing. It also assumes that your argument is 11 or fewer characters, which is a huge assumption.

Comment: Apart from 2 things that potentially invoke *undefined behavior* I'm unsure what you are asking about

Comment: You seem to be asking us to do your homework for you.  We sometimes give hints, but there isn't much room for that here, other than simply that there are two issues to find.

Comment: It assumes that you *have* an argument, by ignoring `argc`.

Comment: it is not a homework, just the notes I got from the lecture im prepairing for the exam and Im really clueless here. I dont get any helpat school.

Comment: WHY do you think there is something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems :

- if the program has no argument `argv[1]` is NULL and in *foo* you do `strcpy(c, NULL);` having an undefined behavior (typically a crash).
- if the firs argument of the program has at least 12 characters `strcpy(c, bar);` will write out of *c*, again with an undefined behavior.

I do not speak about the fact the *strcpy* is in the best case useless because *c* is not used after

A secure version of your program with the minimal changes is :

```
#include <string.h>

void foo (char *bar)
{
  char c[12];

  strncpy(c, bar, sizeof(c) - 1);
  c[sizeof(c) - 1] = 0;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc >= 2)
    foo(argv[1]);
  return(1);
}
```

Comment: there is yet another problem: the program makes no sense :-). it does not do anything.